# cakephp making a front page

Tags: cakephp, random, cakephp-2.0

Im trying to make a front page for a website using cake.

I want to display a random advertisment (adverts listed in advertisements) table. A user has many adverts.

How to i go about doing this with cakephp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can randomly retrive your advertisements from mysql

```
$this->loadModel('Advertisement');
$advertisments = $this->Advertisement->find('all',
'order' => 'rand()');
```

and use $advertisments as an array in your frontpage.

Comment: Where do i put this code? in the pages controller? or just in the page?

Comment: @fuzzy dunlop in the action of the controller you wish to show the ads.

Comment: cake is a MVC... you use code in controllers and results in layouts (view)  for example. you have articles_controller with view function. In the view function you insert the advertisemtns query, for display it in your layour (i hope this explaination is ok for you)

Answer (score 0):

Just get all Adverts belonging to your user with $data = $this->find('all'); 
Then use array_rand() to get a random entry out of your $data array.

Further reading:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php